# Excel using an inputbox get sheet name by selecting sheet tab but not cell within the sheet and not activesheet

Tags: inputbox

I have a Excel workbook that has chart, calculation and data sheets.

What I'm trying to do in VBA is this:

I have a script that will set the calculations sheet up and import the new data into it.  The problem is i have to manually type the name of the data sheet in.  I'm trying to automate the process as much as possible because of the luddites I work with lol!

I'm trying to figure out a way to set up an inputbox so that when it pops it will prompt me to select a different sheet to import the data from.  Then I click the data sheets tab and it uses that sheetname as the sheet to get the data from and kick the rest of the script after its clicked.  Just a one click process within the section of the script that I just described.

I did find this...

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim varCellContent As Range
    Dim strDestinationSheetName As String

    On Error Resume Next
    Set varCellContent = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Choose a sheet by clicking on any cell in it.", Type:=8)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If Not varCellContent Is Nothing Then
        strDestinationSheetName = varCellContent.Parent.Name

        MsgBox ("Sheet = " & strDestinationSheetName)
    End If
End Sub
```

This is kind of what i need but I have to select the cell with this code.  I need to be able to not select the cell.  If they go that far into the worksheet they'll be lost! Lol!

I can't use addins or anthing that needs to be installed because of corporate security

Any help would be apreciated hugely!!